# How to find the entries in one table not like those in another

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `whitelist_email` which looks like this

```
+----+---------------------+-------------+
| id | email_suffix        | create_date |
+----+---------------------+-------------+
|  1 | stackoverflow.com   | 2017-07-07  |
|  2 | example.com         | 2017-07-07  |
```

and a table called `user_info` with a field called `verified_email`. I would like to write a command to find all the rows in `user_info` whose `verified_email` field does not end with any entry in `whitelist_email` to give me a list of new users who need to be vetted. The best I can do with my limited knowledge is

```
SELECT verified_email 
FROM user_info 
WHERE verified_email IN (
    SELECT email_suffix 
    FROM whitelist_email
);
```

Comment: `select verified_email from user_info where right(verified_email, length(verified_email)-INSTR(verified_email, '@')) not in (select email_suffix from whitelist_email);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to `LEFT JOIN` the `user_info` table to the `whitelist_email` table on the condition that the verified email address ends in a whitelisted suffix, and then retain only emails which did *not* match to any known whitelisted email suffix.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM user_info t1
LEFT JOIN whitelist_email t2
    ON t1.verified_email LIKE CONCAT('%', t2.email_suffix)
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

Comment: @MatthewTaylor No, thank you for letting me know it works...you spared me from having to setup  a demo :-)

Comment: @MatthewTaylor You should have!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT verified_email 
from user_info 
where   SUBSTRING(verified_email,INSTR(reverse(verified_email),".")+1,length(verified_email)) 
    not in (select email_suffix from whitelist_email);
```

Comment: This doesn't work in case of mail.yahoo.com for example .

Comment: thanks for your reply, but it doesn't work for me, either.

Answer (score 0):

For example

Table user_info

```
id;verified_email
1;u1@tu.com
2;u2@example.com
```

Table whitelist_email

```
id;email_suffix
1;example.com
2;stackoverflow.com
```

Query

```
select *
from user_info u
where not exists(
  select * 
  from whitelist_email 
  where whitelist_email.email_suffix=substr(u.verified_email,locate('@',u.verified_email)+1)
)
```

Result

```
id,verified_email
1,u1@tu.com
```

It is more efficient to store mail account and mail domain in separate fields.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I think I see the issue - it looks like you have added a '@' to the left of the email address, which is not a valid assumption. (One of the entries in my whitelist is '.edu', for example. I am making the assumption, rightly or wrongly, that any email address that ends in .edu is legit)